# Version mismatch issue with Angular 5 and bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular5

Version issue with Angular 5 and Bootstrap 4
I am working with Angular 5 with Bootstrap 4 but when i run the **npm start** command, i am getting the following error , is there any version issues please let me know ,
I am using node 8.11.1 and npm is 5.6.0

```
To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Error: Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Angular5-Bootstrap4\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:18:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Angular5-Bootstrap4\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-config.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

here is my package.json file code (removed dependencies)

```
{
  "name": "test-data",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? In your `npm log` it says it is a `typescript` error not bootstrap.
I would remove by `npm_modules` and reinstall them with `npm i`, maybe that helps.